# WifiP2P giving inconsistent results on peer discovery

Tags: android, wifip2p

I have the same code running on two devices (Lenovo K50-T5 with Android API 23 running, and One Plus 3T with API 26).

I call discoverPeers on WifiP2pManager and also have overriden onPeersAvailable in WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener instance.

I expect both phones to find each other, but when onPeersAvailable is called WifiP2pDeviceList is empty on One Plus, and on Lenovo WifiP2pDeviceList successfully contains the One Plus phone.

The only conclusions I have here is that either something is missing on Lenovo phone or WifiP2P feature is not reliable and does not work fully. I would like to know if someone had similar experiences, or maybe knows of possible reasons for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that one One Plus the android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION was not granted to the App.

Once the permission was sorted out both phones were able to successfully find each other.